# Trigger code after mouse has stopped

Tags: javascript, dom, mouse

I have a block of code that is triggered on mouse enter. I also have a block of code that detects when the mouse has stopped moving.

I would like the mouseenter code to only run when the mouse has stopped moving within the entered object.

```
// Add events to each dot
for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function (event) {
    var target = event.target;

    // Add a class called moving when follow dot is in a transition
    followDot.classList.add('moving');

    targetsPosition[0] = target.style.left;
    targetsPosition[1] = target.style.top;

    // Detect if the dot is moving left or right
    if (followDot.style.left < targetsPosition[0]) {
      removeMovingClasses();
      followDot.classList.add('moving-right');
    } else if (followDot.style.left > targetsPosition[0]) {
      removeMovingClasses();
      followDot.classList.add('moving-left');
    }

    //
    followDot.style.left = targetsPosition[0];
  });
}
```

The timeout code:

```
// Detect when the mouse has stopped
document.onmousemove = function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    // console.log('mouse stopped');
  }, 300);
}
```

Comment: Define "best"... does this not work?

Comment: Detecting when the mouse has stopped works. However I don't want the code in the first block to run unless the mouse has stopped. I'm unsure how to combine the two.

Comment: What is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want  the mouseenter to trigger unless the mouse has stopped moving within the mouse entered object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution you can fire event when mouse is idle on `div for example` for specific period.

HTML:

```
<h2>fire event when mouse is idle</h2>
<div id="sample">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sample {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 2000;

(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function () {
var $sample = $("#sample");
    $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {

        clearTimeout(idleTimer);

        if (idleState == true) { 

            // Reactivated event
            if($sample.is(":hover")) {
                            alert('mouse has moved again');
                        }

        }

        idleState = false;

        idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 

            // Idle Event
            if($sample.is(":hover")) {
                            alert('mouse has stopped for two seconds');
                        }

            idleState = true; }, idleWait);
    });

    $("body").trigger("mousemove");

});
}) (jQuery)
```

you can change `idleWait` variable to the period you want, (2 sec in this example)

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y1yfycLd/)

i hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I've been able to get it to work on a standard item, however I'm having issues incorporating it with the first code block I pasted above. I'm also using this as a way to get more familiar with vanilla JS, so I'd like to stay away from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine you'll just need to make a small change . Try adding the mousemove event to the area your're targeting instead of the **document** (unless it is the entire document). Also you should wrap your first block in a function to be called once mouse stops .

Example

```
function mouseHasStopped(){
//code in first block...
}

//adding an event listener to whatever element is entered . in this example i'm using "element" as our entered object ...

element.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(mouseHasStopped,300);
});
```

Hope this helps